# how to solve this error : Cannot start. Unable to get local host IP address.; nested exception is: java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: jmeter

[image]

I started jmeter server on both slave machines and now trying to start on master machine and getting this error.

my slave machines ip:

> remote_hosts= ec2-user@xx.xxx.xxx.xx, ec2-user@x.x.xxx.xx

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to kick off a test from your local machine with 2 slaves in [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) you need to:

1. Start JMeter slave process on ec2 instances like:

   ```
   ./jmeter-server.sh any additional parameters
   ```
2. On master machine you need to run ./jmeter.sh script like:

   ```
   ./jmeter -R -n -t test.jmx -l /path/to/result.jtl
   ```

   and it will pick up slaves IP addresses or hostnames from the `remote_hosts` property

Be aware of the following:

1. Port 1099 needs to be open both in your operating system [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) on EC2 instances and [AWS security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-security-groups.html)
2. Slaves need to be able to access your local machine, i.e. if you're behind [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) - it's not gonna work. You will need to define `client.rmi.localport` property and explicitly set 3 ports and make sure that they're open in your firewall.

It's highly unlikely that you will be able to establish connectivity from EC2 machines to your local machine so I would rather recommend moving your master machine to EC2 as well.

More information:

- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)